# Problem with splitting files based on numeric suffix

Tags: linux

I have a file called files.txt and I need to split it based on lines. The command is as follows -

```
split -l 1 files.txt file --numeric-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=4
```

The numeric suffixes here start from file0001 to file9000. But I want it to be from 1 to 9000.
I can't seem to change it when --suffix-length=1, as split exhausted output filenames. Any suggestions using the same split command?

Comment: You can rename the files after splitting.

Comment: Why do you want it like that? When you list files or use wildcards, they're sorted lexicographically, not numerically. So it will order the files `file1 file10  file100 file1000 file11 file110 ...`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `split` will do what you want it to do, though I'm on macOS, so the *nix I'm using is Darwin not Linux; however, a simple shell script would do the trick:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
N=1
cat $1 | while read line
do
    echo "$line" > file$N
    N=`expr $N + 1`
done
```

Assuming you save it as `mysplit` (don't forget `chmod -x mysplit`), then you run it:

```
./mysplit files.txt
```